# How (not) to nest `then` producing promise methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

What is a clean way to use bluepird promisified `fs` methods? `readdir` will produce an array of files and folders, but if I in turn which to loop through the directories it provides, I end up writing something very similar to a callback nesting paradigm (except it doesn't even work). What is the standard practice chaining these promises in such a way that their return values may be looped through?

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs-extra'));
var path = require('path');
var junk = require('junk');

//this does not work
fs.readdirAsync('./node_modules')
  .bind(this)
  .then((modules) => {
    this.allFiles = [];
    modules = modules.filter((item) => junk.not && !/^\./.test(item)); 
    modules.forEach((module, index, modulesArray) => {
      fs.readdirAsync(path.join('node_modules', module)) //ugly af and don't even get files to next `then`!
        .then((files) => { 
          console.log(files); // yep, array of files all right
          this.allFiles.push(files);
        });
    })
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('all of the files', this.allFiles) // => [] no files 
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('error! error!', err);
  })
```

Comment: You could use `async` and `await` some of the promises.

Comment: use named functions

Comment: @zzzzBov Could you be a bit more specific about how that could resolve the issue? Thanks!

Comment: In addition to @ssube answer (that I totally agree), [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/async-functions) is a link to a great article of Jake Archibald explaining `async` and `await`.

Comment: @ssube Is there not a standard bluebird implementation to deal with a situation such as this?

Comment: @1252748 async is the standard way of doing this, it's a language feature. If you're using babel, you can choose which coroutine implementation to use, and I believe bluebird is an option. It's not something library can simply polyfill (unless the transpiler is aware).

Comment: @ssube It's a language feature that [no browsers support](http://caniuse.com/#search=await), as it is a Stage 3 Proposal. So you *must* use a transpiler. Saying they should use it now in JavaScript/node without one is a bit premature.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan "Saying they should use it now in JavaScript/node without one is a bit premature" => Are you saying that I would need a transpiler to use it in a node application?

Comment: @1252748 Yes. You'll need to use babel or TypeScript or something like that.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I never said they should use it without a transpiler, in fact I noted that libraries can't implement async *without* a transpiler. While Babel provides an option to specify the coroutine library, I don't know of an equivalent in TS.

Comment: @ssube Your first comment does not mention transpilers. And, you say "async is the standard way of doing this" which is of course not the case (yet).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Any good articles you can recommend for using babel with a node script?

Comment: @1252748 Sounds like a question better suited for ssube. I only use TypeScript or plain (supported) JavaScript.

Comment: @ssube Any articles you can recommend for using babel with a node script?

Comment: @1252748 babel itself provides good documentation and offers that `babel-node` command to wrap node and automatically transpile scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't returning a promise in your first outer `then`. Therefore your outer promise chain doesn't wait for the files to be read.

You can use `Promise.all` + `map` to do so. A second suggestion from me is to don't use `this` to store your values but pass all needed information through your promise chains. That makes the code much shorter:

```
fs.readdirAsync('./node_modules')
  .then((modules) => {
    return Promise.all(modules.filter((item) => junk.not && !/^\./.test(item))
      .map(module => fs.readdirAsync(path.join('node_modules', module))));
  })
  .then(allFiles => {
    console.log('all of the files', allFiles);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('error! error!', err);
  });
```

Comment: Is brevity the only reason you recommend against binding `this`?

Comment: well, it shortens the code. Otherwise i would need another `.then()` block after  `fs.readdirAsync(path.join('node_modules', module))`

Comment: you mean you would need another for just like `.then((files) => {this.allfiles = files}).then(() => {console.log('all files bound to then', this.allfiles)});`?

Comment: yes, something like that. There is no gain doing this imho

Comment: I agree. This is a great answer. Thanks very much.